# EventListener performance ByID vs. ByTagName

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

Lets say my DOM looks like this

```
<nav id="nav">
    <a>link</a>
    <a>link</a>
    <a>link</a>
</nav>
```

to check for clicks on the links inside Javascript i could write

```
var nav = document.getElementByID("nav")
nav.addEventListener("click", function(event){})
```

or also

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
links.addEventListener("click", function (e){});
```

now i wonder, since the second method (ElementsByTagName) returns an array of the elements,
does that also mean that this will init multiple (in this case 3) EventListeners?
Because a greenhorn like me would then say that the first method is much more performant?!

Comment: Have you tried the second one? Because that won't work.

Comment: ok, so the seconds is more performant because it adds no EventListener instead of one?! I am sorry, i made a bad example. But lets in jquery i add a eventListener on each <a> Element. Wouldn't that mean that 3 EventListeners are added to the page?

Answer (score 1):

Because click events bubble, you can add a single click event listener to the `<nav>` element and receive all clicks to it and its child `<a>` elements.  This is known as event delegation and is more performant than adding a different listener to each `<a>`.

```
document.querySelector('nav').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
        // One of the nav's child a elements was clicked.
        // Now you can do something with it:
        e.target.classList.add('clicked');
    }
});
```